# Mongoose doesn't validate nested array schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema:

```
const SectionSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 24
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 64,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        validate: v => {
            console.log("> section validation test");
            return false;
        }
    }
}, {_id: false});

const InstructionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    columns: [[SectionSchema]]
});
```

For the sake of reordering and simplicity I keep sections in a nested array of columns.
My problem is that no validation of `SectionSchema` is being performed, when I save changes:

```
// Create
const doc = new Instruction();
doc.name = "Test";
await doc.save(); // Save ok

// Later
const doc = await Instruction.findOne({name: "Test"});
doc.columns = [
    [
        {title: "Section1", message: "This is section one in column one.", state: "something"},
        {title: "Section2", message: "This is section two in column one.", state: "something"},
    ],
    [
        {title: "Section1", message: "This is section one in column two."},
        {title: "Section2"},
    ]
];

await doc.save(); // Save ok (doesn't validate?)

doc.columns[0][0].message = ""; // Should fail validation

await doc.save(); // Success...
```

When setting columns the save is successful, that means no validation is being made, including builtin and custom validation for each `SectionSchema` in the column array.

If my assumptions are correct, this is because for mongoose the `columns` field is a mixed type. Mongoose docs doesn't even cover the topic of mixed types validation.

I have tried marking the paths as modified, but that doesn't make any difference:
`doc.markModified('columns.0.0.state');`

What is the solution to `SectionSchema` validating correctly in this case?

Comment: Any particular reason your Instruction Schema has an array of arrays of Section schema: `columns: [[SectionSchema]]`. Why didn't you go for the plain array of schemas: `columns: [SectionSchema]`?

Comment: @codemonkey Like I said, that would be array of sections only. I want array of columns where each column contain sections. I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Do you see `console.log("> section validation test");` in the console when you try to save?

Comment: @codemonkey No I don't. Absolutely no validation is made.